# How to use regex that matches any string whose last two characters are the first two characters in reverse order

Tags: java, python

For example, the regex should match "aa", "aba", "abba", and "asddsa", but not "abab".

Comment: Are you using Java or Python, and if you can't even answer that, then you're not ready to ask a question here.

Comment: Please clearly mention the ASK and the framework and language which you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
^(?=(.)(.)).*\2\1$
```

Note that I used a lookahead for the first two characters, instead of simply matching them. This is because you want to match strings shorter than 4 characters as well. So we don't want to match the first two characters this early.

I capture the first two characters into group 1 and 2, then I match everything in between (`.*`), then I match whatever is matched in group 2, then whatever is matched in group 1 (`\1\2`).

Java:

```
input.matches("^(?=(.)(.)).*\\2\\1$")
```

Python:

```
re.match(r"^(?=(.)(.)).*\2\1$", input)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, it works!

Answer (score 0):

We *could* use a regex here, but honestly it just might be easier to manually do two comparisons for the two sets of letters:

```
String input = "BonzaioB";
int n = input.length();
if (input.charAt(0) == input.charAt(n-1) &&
    input.charAt(1) == input.charAt(n-2)) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

Or in Python:

```
input = "BonzaioB"
n = len(input)
if (input[0] == input[n-1] and input[1] == input[n-2]) :
    print("MATCH")
else:
    print("NO MATCH")
```

Incidentally, this would probably outperform a regex based solution, as it would require no scanning of the entire string, nor additional storage space.